# Faraday - Multiple GET param request to Freebase API

Tags: ruby, freebase, faraday

I am stuck trying to get Topic information from the Freebase API. This is mostly a Ruby Faraday question anyways.

So I request at the following path:
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02676m4?limit=20&filter=/film/film_series/films_in_series&filter=/common/topic/article

Notice how there are TWO &filter. This works just fine using my web browser. When doing either the following on Ruby, though:

```
response = Faraday.get 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02676m4', {
        'limit' => 20,
        'filter' => ['/film/film_series/films_in_series', '/common/topic/article'],
        'key' => 'my_key_here'
    }, { 'Accept' => self.Headers_Accept }
```

or...

```
response = Faraday.get 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02676m4', {
        'limit' => 20,
        'filter' => '/film/film_series/films_in_series&filter=/common/topic/article',
        'key' => 'my_key_here'
    }, { 'Accept' => self.Headers_Accept }
```

or...

```
response = Faraday.get 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02676m4?limit=20&filter=/film/film_series/films_in_series&filter=/common/topic/article&key=my_key_here', {}, { 'Accept' => self.Headers_Accept }
```

**Then Filters are ignored by the API.** I get a huge response with every single piece of information regarding my topic.

You can replicate the result by performing the query with *no filters*:
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02676m4?limit=20

**Question:**
Anyone can come up with a reason why I get this issue through Faraday, but not when accessing directly through my browser?

**Extra tip:**
If I only use *one* filter on the Faraday request, it works just fine. But I really need to use more than one filter.

**Freebase Topic API:**
http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Topic_API

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like the Faraday bug fixed by this pull request: https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/pull/199

Comment: Hm, so was this fixed? Or do I need to provide some extra parameter so that it works on my case?